# How do you split a dataset into multiple subset then run a function (specifically areapl) through each of them?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, subset, polygon

i am trying to calculate the area of the convex hulls of the subsets of a bigger dataset. Let's say here is the dataset i am working on, two variables in three groups:

```
a1 <- rnorm(150, mean=2, sd=3)

a2 <- rnorm(150, mean =10, sd=1)

g_a <- c(rep("a", len=50),rep("b", len=50),rep("c", len=50))

group <- as.data.frame(cbind(a1, a2,g_a))

names(group) <- c("v1", "v2","ID")
```

Ideally I would like to write a code to calculate the area of the convex hull of each group.

Here is what I did, first i find out the coordinates of each convex hull:

```
library(tidyverse)

hull_a <- group %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  slice(chull(v1, v2))
```

then i want to use areapl in the package splancs to calculate the area of each convex hull. 
I split the hull_a data frame as a list, and try to use sapply to calculate the area of each convex hull:

```
library(splancs)

split_hull <- split(hull_a, hull_a$ID)

sapply(split_hull, function(matrix){areapl(cbind(hull_a$v1, hull_a$v2))})
```

However, instead of the respective convexhull area of the three groups, I get the sum of the convex hull areas three times.

I guess another way is to subset the dataset manually and calculate each convex hull separately.

```
a <- subset(hull_a, ID=="a")

as.matrix(a)[,1:2]%>% areapl # then repeat for the other 2 groups
```

But i wonder if there is a more elegant way to do it, perhaps with a for loop?

Comment: Please don't use `as.data.frame(cbind`, instead `data.frame(...)` is better.  also, the `slice` part is not clear.  Are you subsetting the data?

Comment: If you had constructed with `data.frame(...)`, `group %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(new = list(chull(v1, v2))) %>% unnest(c(new))`